# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when dockerizing react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose

I have a react project with Webpack which I'm trying to dockerize it following [this article](https://medium.com/@andyccs/webpack-and-docker-for-development-and-deployment-ae0e73243db4#.v0vhqvvjl).

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.14.1

RUN npm install webpack -g

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package.json /tmp/
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm install

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . /usr/app/
RUN cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/app/

RUN webpack

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=4000

CMD [ "/usr/local/bin/node", "--experimental-modules", "./src/index.js" ]

EXPOSE 4000
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
ex_dashboard:
  build: .
  ports:
  - "80:4000"
  volumes:
  - .:/usr/app/:rw
  environment:
  - NODE_ENV=dev
  command: >
    sh -c '
      if test -d node_modules; 
      then 
        echo node_modules_exists ; 
      else 
        cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/app/dashboard; 
      fi && 
      npm install && 
      /usr/local/bin/node --experimental-modules ./src/index.js
    '
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, everything goes well until I encounter this error:

> ```
> ex_dashboard_1  | (node:18) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
> ex_dashboard_1  | file:///usr/app/src/index.js:9
> ex_dashboard_1  |   <Provider store={store}>
> ex_dashboard_1  |   ^
> ex_dashboard_1  | 
> ex_dashboard_1  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> ex_dashboard_1  |     at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:66:18)
> ex_dashboard_1  |     at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:37:21)
> ```

The whole project works well if I just run it by `npm start` or build it by `npm run build`. But I don't know why this happens in docker container.

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "explore_dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A dashboard for the Explore project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.basalam.dev/data/explore_dashboard.git"
  },
  "author": "Gh.Sherafati",
  "license": "ISC",
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  }
}
```

And `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const { env } = process;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: env.NODE_ENV,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV) }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve('./src/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './build',
    hot: true,
  },
  devtool: env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : undefined,
};
```

Also `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import App from './components/App';
import './scss/main.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);

module.hot.accept();
```

Comment: make sure you use same node version on your docker and your host. What version do you use for your host?

Comment: @Smankusors it's `12.14.1` and I tried `FROM node:12.14.1`. But it didn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solve the issue by using `nginx` and running the build version in the container getting help from [this great article](https://medium.com/swlh/dockerizing-a-react-application-with-docker-and-nginx-19e88ef8e99a).

The new `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` follows:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.14.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  explore_dashboard:
    container_name: explore_dashboard
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile:
        Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
```

Now I'm able to run the app on `http://127.0.0.1:8081/` running:

```
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--experimental-modules` flag can be used to enable support for ECMAScript modules (ES modules).

#### option 1

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "exec node --experimental-modules index.js"]
```

#### option 2

```
CMD exec node --experimental-modules index.js
```

[Full Docs:](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Comment: I've added the flag both in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you please share the package.json file?

Comment: Thanks, please update the flag both in Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in the question too.

Comment: Please try to change the Docker file to: CMD /usr/local/bin/node --experimental-modules ./src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, delete the `volumes:` and the rather long-winded `command:`.

The important thing that’s going on here is that your `index.js` file actually includes JSX constructs that React uses; it’s not plain Javascript and `node` can’t run it directly.  In your `Dockerfile` you `RUN webpack`, which transpiles this into plain Javascript.  The `volumes:` overwrite all of this with whatever content is on your local system; that does not include a transpilation step, so you don’t have valid Javascript for Node to run.

(It might work to put an explicit call to `webpack` in that `command:`.  This assumes your host and container `node_modules` are compatible, and it is literally duplicating everything the `Dockerfile` does to build the image in the `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Nothing stops you from installing Node on your host system (if you don’t already have it), doing live development using the Webpack dev server, and then using Docker for a final packaging step.  That’s probably much more convenient than introducing an isolation system like Docker and then trying to work around all of its features to emulate a local development setup.

Comment: I deleted `volumes:` and the `command:` part but the error still stands. I need docker to make sure the service always is running in the target machine. I don't know any other ways to do it

Comment: Do you also need to point `node` at the output of Webpack; `CMD node ./dist/index.js`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. I'm not good at dockerizing and I'm not sure what's the best practice to run the app. In the local machine I run it by `npm start`, but that's not the case for running production build here